# Unresolved dependencies error when following Jersey 2.0 user guide

Tags: java, maven, jersey, pom.xml

Update:  This does not/should not occur anymore, see accepted answer.  If you are facing this problem with some other jar, it is typically a transient thing.  You can try some of the workaround suggested in other answers.

I am following the instructions from [Jersey 2.0 user guide](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html).  When I reach 1.3 (running the project, I get the following failure:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxx-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx.restapi:xxx-service:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2 in https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of snapshot-repository.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The problem seems to be that there is no `https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar`

If we go up to `https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/`  we see that the folders and jar files inside those folders are renamed with a suffix of `-b01` etc.

The pom itself does not have any direct reference to this annotations jar.  So I guess the question is:  How do I adjust that dependency?  What do I put in the POM file that will get that dependency resolved correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meanwhile, this problem no longer occurs. `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2` is now [available on Maven central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/).

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the following the `pom.xml` to resolve this problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-b04</version>
</dependency>
```

depending on when you are viewing this, you should go to `https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/` and check what is the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

javax.annotation-api.jar version 1.2 is published on the java.net maven repository @ https://maven.java.net

follow this link to search for version 1.2 :

https://maven.java.net/index.html#nexus-search;gav~javax.annotation~javax.annotation-api~1.2~~

you can instruct maven to fetch artifacts from java.net maven repository by adding it to the  section of your pom.xml. e.g.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net.repo</id>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: For some reason I had to open that link twice before I saw search results but it works :) Thank You.