# Jersey 2.0 "Getting Started" guide, mainClass not found

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

Hi I am trying to follow the [Getting Started guide](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html) for Jersey 2.0.

I did steps 1.1 and 1.2 as is. No problem there.

For step 1.3 I had a problem cause maven could not find the javax-annotation 1.2 but I solved it following the advice [of another Stackoverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829290/unresolved-dependencies-error-when-following-jersey-2-0-user-guide) and added a repository to my pom.

So`mvn clean test` passes with no problems, BUT when I try to run `mvn clean exec:java` I get back

```
[WARNING] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The pom.xml is the one created by the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.0
```

where the only addition I 've made is the following:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>java.net.repo</id>
    <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

In case it is of interest this is the output of `mvn -version`

```
 Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 10:44:56+0200)
 Maven home: /usr/share/maven
 Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
 Default locale: el_GR, platform encoding: UTF-8
 OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Do you have a class named `Main`?

Comment: yeap, created by default by maven under src/main/java/com/example. As a matter of fact there are two classes automatically created Main.java and MyResource.java (described in the user guide)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your error. This has nothing to do with Jersey; it's an error you're making with Maven. `mvn clean exec:java` says: "delete all the .class files and then try to run the `Main` .class file". Since you deleted it, Maven can't find it. Here's a solution:

```
mvn clean compile exec:java
```

This should fix the problem in your question. This says "delete all the .class files, recompile them from source and then try to run the `Main` .class file"

To get past the next error you'll see, delete the `<scope>test</scope>` line from the client dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

To:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not know about maven, but I assumed that exec:java would depend on compile. In any case, however, even with removing the scope from pom.xml I now get a bunch of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientConfig. I think jersey's getting started guide is not for starters:-)

Comment: @user2465039 read the bottom of my answer.  It shows how to fix that.

Comment: Thanks! I had removed the wrong scope :-) Someone needs to update the guide though. I would vote for you but I do not have enough points here yet:-)

Comment: Great answer, works like a charm!  I am surprised that Jersey Official documentation has so many bugs though.